# addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName,range:NSMakeRangeの文末バグに関して

Tags: objective-c

```
[theText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                value: UIColor.redColor    
                range:selectedRenge];
```

の文にて選択された範囲だけ赤色に文字を変えるという処理をしているのですが、
**文末**でこの処理をするとそのあとに入力した文字まで赤色に変わってしまうバグに悩まされています。 githubにソースを添付します。ご教授のほど宜しくお願いします。

//NoteFunction.mにてこの記述をしています

[githubのソースコドです](https://github.com/yasi1015/GraduateCreat.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

プロパティ「attributedText」を設定した後に、プロパティ「typingAttributes」を再設定すれば良いと思います。例えば、次の様なコードです。

```
UIFont *font = self->tv.font; // フォントを取得
self->tv.typingAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor,
                              NSFontAttributeName: font};
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！
typingAttributesプロパティというものを初めて知りました、
勉強を深めたいと思います